# Shake visual effect on iPhone (NOT shaking the device)

Tags: iphone, core-animation

On login failure, I'd prefer to avoid showing an alert, it's too fleeting. Showing the alert and then showing the text somewhere on the login screen seems like duplication.

So I'd like for it to graphically shake my login view when the user enters the wrong user ID and password like the Mac login screen does.

Anyone know if there's a way to pull this off, or have any suggestions for another effect I could use?

Comment: 5 yrs later .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356051

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I think this is a more efficient solution:

Swift:

```
let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation( keyPath:"transform" )
anim.values = [
    NSValue( CATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-5, 0, 0 ) ),
    NSValue( CATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation( 5, 0, 0 ) )
]
anim.autoreverses = true
anim.repeatCount = 2
anim.duration = 7/100

viewToShake.layer.addAnimation( anim, forKey:nil )
```

Obj-C:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation * anim = [ CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform" ] ;
anim.values = @[ 
    [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ], 
    [ NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation( 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) ] 
] ;
anim.autoreverses = YES ;
anim.repeatCount = 2.0f ;
anim.duration = 0.07f ;

[ viewToShake.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;
```

Only one animation object is created and it's all performed at the CoreAnimation level.

Answer (score 59):

Using iOS 4+ block based UIKit animations (and loosely based on on jayccrown's answer):

```
- (void)shakeView:(UIView *)viewToShake
{
    CGFloat t = 2.0;
    CGAffineTransform translateRight  = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, t, 0.0);
    CGAffineTransform translateLeft = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -t, 0.0);

    viewToShake.transform = translateLeft;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.07 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2.0];
        viewToShake.transform = translateRight;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
                viewToShake.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            } completion:NULL];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: This should be the top answer to the question, since all of the above answers will not work properly (without modifications or omitting the view parameter) with ARC turned on. Use blocks!

Comment: yup, this is the better answer, you might not want to check `finished` though, otherwise you may end up with an odd transform

Comment: You can do this w just a single autoreversing animation--no need for completion blocks. (I posted code below)

Comment: This had a quirk in my case where another view was being shaken at the same time. The CAKeyframeAnimation answer below @nielsbot worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 40):

I had seen some wobble animation and changed it to shake a view t pixels upright and downleft:

```
- (void)earthquake:(UIView*)itemView
{
    CGFloat t = 2.0;

    CGAffineTransform leftQuake  = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, t, -t);
    CGAffineTransform rightQuake = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -t, t);

    itemView.transform = leftQuake;  // starting point

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"earthquake" context:itemView];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.07];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(earthquakeEnded:finished:context:)];

    itemView.transform = rightQuake; // end here & auto-reverse

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)earthquakeEnded:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context 
{
    if ([finished boolValue]) 
    {
        UIView* item = (UIView *)context;
        item.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a tutorial that details how to do it in Cocoa.  Should be the same for the iPhone (or at least quite similar).

http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/27/core-animation-tutorial-window-shake-effect/

Answer (score 6):

Simply changing the X coordinate of the center property of your view might do the trick.  If you haven't done any core animation before it's pretty straight-forward.

First, start an animation right, then listen for it to finish, and then move back to the left, and so on.  Getting the timing down so it "feels right" might take a while.

```
- (void)animationFinishCallback:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context
{
  if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"MoveRight"]) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"MoveLeft" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationFinishCallback:finished:context:)];

    myView.center = CGRectMake(newX, newY);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also create an animation and apply it to the view's `CALayer`. This would let you use, for example, a `CAKeyframeAnimation` which would let you fine-tune the animation. For an animation like this, you'll probably need that level of flexibility.

Comment: see my answer below--it uses a single CoreAnimation animation which is automatically removed when the animation completes... no need for callbacks or multiple animate blocks

Answer (score 4):

This UIView category snippet worked for me. It's using 3 CABasingAnimations applied to view's layer.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#define Y_OFFSET 2.0f
#define X_OFFSET 2.0f
#define ANGLE_OFFSET (M_PI_4*0.1f)

@interface UIView (shakeAnimation)

-(BOOL)isShakeAnimationRunning;
-(void)startShakeAnimation;
-(void)stopShakeAnimation;

@end



@implementation UIView (shakeAnimation)

-(BOOL)isShakeAnimationRunning{
     return [self.layer animationForKey:@"shake_rotation"] != nil;
}

-(void)startShakeAnimation{
    CFTimeInterval offset=(double)arc4random()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    self.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, -ANGLE_OFFSET*0.5);
    self.transform=CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, -X_OFFSET*0.5f, -Y_OFFSET*0.5f);

    CABasicAnimation *tAnim=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    tAnim.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    tAnim.byValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:X_OFFSET];
    tAnim.duration=0.07f;
    tAnim.autoreverses=YES;
    tAnim.timeOffset=offset;
    [self.layer addAnimation:tAnim forKey:@"shake_translation_x"];

    CABasicAnimation *tyAnim=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
    tyAnim.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    tyAnim.byValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Y_OFFSET];
    tyAnim.duration=0.06f;
    tyAnim.autoreverses=YES;
    tyAnim.timeOffset=offset;
    [self.layer addAnimation:tyAnim forKey:@"shake_translation_y"];

    CABasicAnimation *rAnim=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    rAnim.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    rAnim.byValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:ANGLE_OFFSET];
    rAnim.duration=0.15f;
    rAnim.autoreverses=YES;
    rAnim.timeOffset=offset;
    [self.layer addAnimation:rAnim forKey:@"shake_rotation"];
}
-(void)stopShakeAnimation{
    [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"shake_translation_x"];
    [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"shake_translation_y"];
    [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"shake_rotation"];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        self.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(self.transform, ANGLE_OFFSET*0.5);
        self.transform=CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.transform, X_OFFSET*0.5, Y_OFFSET*0.5f);
    }];
}

@end
```

Hope it helpes someone :)

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7.0 or later, UIKit keyframe animation is available.

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

    NSInteger repeatCount = 8;
    NSTimeInterval duration = 1.0 / (NSTimeInterval)repeatCount;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++) {
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:i * duration relativeDuration:duration animations:^{
            CGFloat dx = 5.0;
            if (i == repeatCount - 1) {
                viewToShake.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            } else if (i % 2) {
                viewToShake.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -dx, 0.0);
            } else {
                viewToShake.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, +dx, 0.0);
            }
        }];
    }
} completion:completion];
```

Answer (score 1):

very easy shake categorie for UIVoew

https://github.com/jonasschnelli/UIView-I7ShakeAnimation

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is already answered, but since I have already implemented something like this previously, I feel it can't hurt to add it:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *shakeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
NSArray *transformValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((M_PI)/64)],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(-((M_PI)/64))],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((M_PI)/64)],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(-((M_PI)/64))],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((M_PI)/64)],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(-((M_PI)/64))],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],                                
                        nil];

[shakeAnimation setValues:transformValues];

NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.14f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.28f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.42f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.57f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.71f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.85f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], 
                  nil];

[shakeAnimation setKeyTimes:times];

shakeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
shakeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
shakeAnimation.duration = 0.6f;

[self.viewToShake.layer addAnimation:shakeAnimation forKey:@"anim"];
```

Also, since you want the shaking to indicate that the user failed to log in, you might also consider adding this animation that tints the screen red while the screen shakes:

```
//Put this in the header (.h)
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *redView;

//Put this in the implementation (.m)
@synthesize redView;

//Put this in viewDidLoad
self.redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.redView.layer.opacity = 0.0f;
self.redView.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

//Put this wherever you check if the login failed
CAKeyframeAnimation *redTint = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
NSArray *transformValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2f],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],                                
                           nil];

[redTint setValues:transformValues];

NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], 
                  nil];

[redTint setKeyTimes:times];

redTint.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
redTint.removedOnCompletion = NO;
redTint.duration = 0.6f;

[self.redView.layer addAnimation:shakeAnimation forKey:@"anim"];
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using Auto Layout, I adapted Chris Miles' answer but animated NSLayoutConstraints like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *left  = ...
NSLayoutConstraint *right = ...

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.08 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
    left.constant  = 15.0;
    right.constant = 25.0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.08 animations:^{
            left.constant  = 20.0;
            right.constant = 20.0;
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        } completion:NULL];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I used for constraints which I set in my storyboard. Without using animateWithDuration.

```
@IBOutlet var balloonHorizontalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.04, target: self, selector: "animateBalloon", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func animateBalloon() {
    switch balloonHorizontalConstraint.constant {
    case -46:
        balloonHorizontalConstraint.constant = -50
    default:
        balloonHorizontalConstraint.constant = -46
    }
}
```

In my case the animation just kept on going, but I pop my viewcontroller after a duration of a few seconds, this stops my timer aswell.