# Make iOS & Mac UI elements 'shake'

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, user-interface

I'm sure you have seen it before; when typing passwords on the mac, if you get it wrong, it shakes!

What I want to know is, is there a way of doing this with UI objects in XCode (on either iOS or Mac platforms).

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294451/animating-uitextfield-to-indicate-a-wrong-password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/02/27/core-animation-tutorial-window-shake-effect/) on the excellent [cimgf.com](http://www.cimgf.com) which describes what you want.