# Animation for object

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, cabasicanimation

I'm programming on objective-c. Can I create an animation with CABasicAnimation for object that used 2 animations at the same time? For example, object is scaling and shaking at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  In fact, you could do it with a CAKeyFrame, CABasic, or even a UIView animation.  This should work great [modified from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1632493/945847)

```
- (void)earthquake:(UIView*)itemView
{
    CGFloat t = 2.0;

    CGAffineTransform leftQuake  = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, t, -t);
    CGAffineTransform rightQuake = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -t, t);

    itemView.transform = leftQuake;  // starting point

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"earthquake" context:itemView];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:5];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.07];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    itemView.transform = rightQuake; // end here & auto-reverse
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.00 animations:^{
         itemView.alpha = 0.0f;
    }];
}
```

Comment: If someone could format my code properly, I'd be much obliged seeig as I typed this out on an iPhone.