# how to put shake animation on uiimageview?

Tags: uiimageview, cabasicanimation

I've been trying to implement this but couldn't find any code that could shake it like iPhone app shakes while deleting them!

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = 
                         [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[animation setDuration:0.05];
[animation setRepeatCount:8];
[animation setAutoreverses:YES];
[animation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
               CGPointMake([lockView center].x - 20.0f, [lockView center].y)]];
[animation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
               CGPointMake([lockView center].x + 20.0f, [lockView center].y)]];
[[lockView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: See this answer, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632364/shake-visual-effect-on-iphone-not-shaking-the-device

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can achieve this by the following code, you have define the rotation angle from and to.

> ```
> CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
>    [anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
>    [anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/16]]; // rotation angle
>    [anim setDuration:0.1];
>    [anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
>    [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
>    [[imageView layer] addAnimation:anim forKey:@"iconShake"];
> ```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
- (void)animateImage 
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

    CGFloat wobbleAngle = 0.06f;

    NSValue* valLeft = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
    NSValue* valRight = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
    animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:valLeft, valRight, nil];

    animation.autoreverses = YES;  
    animation.duration = 0.125;
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;  

    [[lockView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shakeAnimation"];
}
```